# Rewrite Rule exclude certain strings from (.*) in Regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I currently have the following htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule    (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do I make it exclude 2 certain strings like : 'template' and 'image'?

I read other posts but it was not clear to me.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want. Your question could be interpreted in several ways. Could you give examples of things you'd like to match and not match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a negating rewrite condition

Like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(template|image)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which effectively doesn't rewrite any urls pointing to things in the image and template folder.

- [Documentation on `RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)
- [Very good tutorial about htaccess and also goes deeply into url rewriting, worth the read](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)